# Does the size of a long equal to the size of a word

Tags: c, linux, cpu-word, long-integer, ptrace

Hello I'm programming under Linux ( In C ).

When i use ptrace() to read data, it returns a word.
In all the examples I see people using a long to read the input.
Does a Long always have the same size of a word?
I know that a word is the natural size with which a processor is handling data (the register size). But does that also apply to long's on different architectures etc?

```
 OValue_t outputValue;
 //.su_word is a long
 outputValue.su_word = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA,Process.ProcId,address,0); 
 printf("word  : %ld\n", outputValue.su_word);
 printf("int8 : %i\n", outputValue.su_int8);
```

EDIT: Thanks to Krzysztof Kosiński/unwind and the answer by Jonathan Leffler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc) I understand that ptrace returns a long and a long is big enough for a word.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3024/lp64-1/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux API defines `ptrace` to always return `long`.

```
long ptrace(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid,
            void *addr, void *data);
```

On Linux, the size of `long` is equal to the machine word size (32-bit on 32-bit machines, 64-bit on 64-bit machines, and so on). As far as I know, this is true on all major architectures which have Linux ports.

Note that this is not true on Windows, where `long` is 32-bit even on x64 - but since `ptrace` is a Linux-specific call, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

Examples use `long` since that's how the [function is documented](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) to work, the prototype is:

```
long ptrace(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid, void *addr, void *data);
```

There's even a note in the manual page saying:

> The size of a "word" is determined by the operating-system variant (e.g., for 32-bit Linux it is 32 bits).

I think it just as well have been declared to return `int`, since `int` is supposed to be a platform's "natural" integer size, which I think is the "word size" for that platform in typical cases.

The function does *not* assume that the `long` has more precision than "a word", as far as I could tell from the manual page. It uses a return value of -1 to signal errors, but since that can of course be a valid value as well, requires you to also check `errno`.

Comment: Thank you, but in the manual it says 'Read a word at the address', so how can they assume a long is large enough to store a word on different platforms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc Jonathan's answer gave me the answer

Comment: `int` is not equal to word size on x86-64 and most other 64-bit systems.

Answer (score -2):

The only rule is that a **long** must be *at least* the size of a **word** (int). Beyond that it's up to the machine architecture and the compiler writer. You could legally have char = short = int = long = long long.

Comment: `int` is not defined as equal to the word size, there is only a recommendation that it should be the fastest available integer type. In practice, `int` is 32-bit even on 64-bit machines, which means it is smaller than word size.